# Can Xcode debugging be limited to only a background thread?

Tags: xcode, multithreading, debugging

I'm trying to debug code running on a background thread (not the main thread). When stepping through the code though, it continually also breaks in the main thread, making it very hard to follow the flow as the debugger jumps between the code of interest to something unrelated in the main thread.

Is it possible to turn off breakpoints for a thread so I can more easily step through the code of interest?

Comment: you can run project, pause it and then, in debug navigator, you can right click threads you don't want to run and click "suspend thread"

Comment: Yes, although I'm not sure I want to suspend the thread. I just don't want a step operation from my thread to cause another one to stop. Maybe that would work though. I also started using right-click - Continue to Here in the thread I'm debugging. That helped, but isn't as convenient as simply stepping.